# Double integration of Greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Integration of double integral of.
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^{y-2} \lfloor x + y \rfloor \,dx\,dy
$$

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide context for this question.  What class is this for?  What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: note that for any  $y$ $\in [0,2]$, we have  $y-2 \leq 0$, hence your second integral  which is from $0$ to  $y-2$   can be inverted to get the right region of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the Region of the plane $$\{(x,y)\mid y\in [0,2],x\in[0,2-y]\}$$
Then note that
\begin{align*} & [\dots]\\\text{if  }\ & 0\ge x+y<1\quad \lfloor x+y\rfloor=0\\
\text{if  }\ & 1\ge x+y<2\quad \lfloor x+y\rfloor=1\\
& [\dots]
\end{align*}
and so on for the various integer values.
Can you identify these regions in the picture? What is their area?

Answer (score 1):

A floor function is rather annoying to integrate (in my opinion), but you have a very easy area over which you integrate: the triangle with vertices $(-2,0), (0,0)$ and $(0,2)$. You can work out what the value of the floor function $\lfloor x+y\rfloor$ will be on this triangle:

- $\lfloor x+y\rfloor = 0 \iff 0 \leq x+y < 1 \iff -x \leq y < -x+1$, in other words, the area between $y = -x$ and $y = -x+1$
- Similarly, we find areas where $\lfloor x+y\rfloor = 1$, $-1$ and $-2$.

[image: Area of integration]

Now, consider the fact that
$$\int\int_D  dx dy = \text{Area}(D)$$
Can you combine these to solve your integral?

Comment: This is exactly my answer, but expanded and with a great picture, which I was about to draw. So good job :)